# Deserialize XML with BOM

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize an xml with this code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrafficJunctions));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(XmlPath))
{
    var test = (TrafficJunctions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

But get the following exception:

```
XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Apparently there is a BOM at the beginning of the xml. I know that I have to remove it, but I don't understand how to do it for before deserialization. Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution (Credit to canton7):**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrafficJunctions));
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(XmlPath))
{
    var test = (TrafficJunctions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're using a `StringReader`, not a `StreamReader`. A `StringReader` will literally read the string you give it, so your deserializer is trying to deserialize a file path as if it was an XML document, which won't work. `StreamReader` will open the file at the path you give it and return its contents

Comment: The error indicates your definition for the class TrafficJunctions does not match the xml.  Sometime it is just an extra space that gives this error.  Other times the namespace (URL) need to be added as an attribute to the c# class.

Comment: Thank you canton7, changing from `StringReader` to `StreamReader`  solved the issue.  I used this service and relied on the method given: https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp

Comment: Yeah, the `xml` on that website is supposed to be a string containing the XML, not a file path